# How do I remove lines between ListViews on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I'm using two `ListView`s like this:

```
<ListView
   android:id="@+id/ListView"
   android:text="@string/Website"
   android:layout_height="30px"
   android:layout_width="150px"
   android:scrollbars="none"
   android:transcriptMode="normal"/>
<ListView
   android:id="@+id/ListView1"
   android:text="@string/Website"
   android:layout_height="30px"
   android:layout_width="150px"
   android:scrollbars="none"
   android:transcriptMode="normal"/>
```

There is one blank line between the two `ListView`s. How do I remove it?

Comment: Do you have two separate ListViews showing different lists or do you mean you have a line between items in your ListView?

Comment: Is it "blank" or "black" line? Since the question got edited by someone other than the OP. There is a difference between those

Comment: @deepthi, would you consider marking one of the answers as accepted?

Answer (score 973):

To remove the separator between items in the same ListView, here is the solution:

```
getListView().setDivider(null);
getListView().setDividerHeight(0);
```

[developer.android.com # ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)

Or, if you want to do it in XML:

```
android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```

Comment: for some reason, setting it in the XML didn't work for me. had to set it in the code.

Comment: Worked in XML for me.  Should put in the <ListView></Listview>. Wonder why this was not accepted as the right answer.

Comment: do we need to make both (nullify and zeroify) or is just one enough?

Comment: Using the 'com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView', I was able to use the XML method successfully.

Comment: @Pranav. Please teacher, let's write about programming. Thank you.

Comment: Weirdly only dividerHeight=0 didnt work, only divider=@null did. Why?

Comment: maybe OP is inactive on SE

Answer (score 98):

1. If you want to remove a divider line, use this code:

   ```
   android:divider="@null"
   ```
2. If you want to add a space instead of a divider line:

   ```
   android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
   android:dividerHeight="5dp"
   ```

So, you can use any drawable or color in the divider attribute.

Answer (score 67):

There are different ways to achieve this, but I'm not sure which one is the best (I don't even know is there is a best way). I know at least two different ways to do this in a ListView:

**1. Set divider to null:**

1.1. Programmatically

```
yourListView.setDivider(null);
```

1.2. XML

This goes inside your ListView element.

```
android:divider="@null"
```

**2. Set divider to transparent and set its height to 0 to avoid adding space between listview elements:**

2.1. Programmatically:

```
yourListView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(android.R.color.transparent));
yourListView.setDividerHeight(0);
```

2.2. XML

```
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```

Comment: In certain situations there seems to be an issue with simply setting the divider color to transparent. My ListView elements each had a solid-colored, semi-transparent background. When I was using the second method of hiding the divider, a "divider" still seemed to appear. When I switched to the first method, the "divider" disappeared.

Answer (score 32):

Set divider to null:

**JAVA**

```
  listview_id.setDivider(null);
```

**XML**

```
<ListView 
  android:id="@+id/listview"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:divider="@null"
  />
```

Answer (score 27):

In XML:

```
android:divider="@null"
```

Or in Java:

```
listView.setDivider(null);
```

Answer (score 18):

```
   <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/list"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:divider="@null"
  android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 12):

You can put below property in listview tag

```
android:divider="@null"
```

(or)
programmatically `listview.Divider(null);`
here `listview` is `ListView` reference.

Answer (score 10):

Or in XML:

```
android:divider="@drawable/list_item_divider"
android:dividerHeight="1dp"
```

You can use a color for the drawable (e.g. #ff112233), but be aware, that pre-cupcake releases have a bug in which the color cannot be set. Instead a 9-patch or a image must be used..

Comment: Or you can even use the standard Android drawable for the divider: `@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_...`

Answer (score 9):

You can try the following. It worked for me...

```
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```

Answer (score 7):

I find it easier to implement it in the XML file as it can be harder to trace the line of code in a class with hundreds of lines.
For the XML you can use "null":

```
android:divider="@null"
```

Answer (score 5):

For ListFragment use

```
getListView().setDivider(null)
```

after the list has been obtained.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove lines from

⛔ Problem

```
Having lines between items from <ListView>
```

✅ Solution

```
add an attribute android:drivider="@null"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you adding an image that tells more than thousand words. :-) Just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If this `android:divider="@null"` doesn't work, maybe changing your ListViews for Recycler Views?

Answer (score -1):

```html
String txt = ( (TextView) view).getText().toString();
adapter.remove(txt);
```

[image]

Comment: This is not related to the question.