# How to remove the border in a Listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

On Android, how can the Line which appears in a `listview` at the bottom of Lists be removed?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

do this

```
myListview.setDivider(null);
```

This should help you.

Comment: If you are inside an activity that extends ListActivity (custom adapter), it would be getListView().setDivider(null);

Comment: @rohitmandiwal can you help answer this question please?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358015/android-listview-inside-cardview-ontouch-listener-conflict-sensitivity

Answer (score 56):

Another option would be to set a transparent color for the android:divider attribute:

```
<ListView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:divider="#00000000"
/>
```

Comment: I like this better; configuring things like dividers should be less obtrusive.

Answer (score 20):

[see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914477/how-to-remove-line-inbetween-two-listviews-in-android) to more info:-

```
getListView().setDivider(null);
getListView().setDividerHeight(0);
```

Or, if you want to do it in XML:

```
android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```

Answer (score 6):

Great answers. I decided to use this in ListView for better readability than colour "#00xxxxxx". transparent is a system colour available by android platform.

```
 android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 2):

Please write this one after defining your listview:

```
Yourlistview.setDivider(null); // Will remove the divider
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set this property in your Style:

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListView">
        <Setter Property="SeparatorVisibility" Value="None"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```